# Information integrity gets lost when P and Q receive 4-digit cousins

Tags: php, rsa

I have the following problem. When P and Q receive 4-digit prime values, the integrity of the information falls apart at the time of encoding and decoding it. Does anyone know why?

I'm breaking the blocks smaller than N.

```
Gen Q and P
gen p: 1009 and gen q: 1013


Gen oN and N
gen N: 1022117 and gen oN: 1020096

Gen E
gen E: 983743

Gen D
gen D: 695359


Pré encrypt
Array ( [0] => 116104 [1] => 111109 [2] => 115111 [3] => 110 ) 

encrypting

116104 ^ 983743 mod 1022117 =244657
111109 ^ 983743 mod 1022117 =623942
115111 ^ 983743 mod 1022117 =619197
110 ^ 983743 mod 1022117 =962437

decrypting

244657 ^ 695359 mod 1022117 =392979
623942 ^ 695359 mod 1022117 =856471
619197 ^ 695359 mod 1022117 =28780
962437 ^ 695359 mod 1022117 =455046
```

The RSA algorithm is too large to be put here. And even if I put a part of it would not work because there are many dependencies.

The algorithm below works with cousins up to 3

```
Gen Q and P
gen p: 109 and gen q: 113

Gen oN and N
gen N: 12317 and gen oN: 12096

Gen E
gen E: 3889

Gen D
gen D: 1297


Pré codificando
Array ( [0] => 116 [1] => 104 [2] => 111 [3] => 109 [4] => 115 [5] => 111 [6] => 110 ) 

Encrypting
116 ^ 3889 mod 12317 =3604
104 ^ 3889 mod 12317 =6862
111 ^ 3889 mod 12317 =11992
109 ^ 3889 mod 12317 =5341
115 ^ 3889 mod 12317 =551
111 ^ 3889 mod 12317 =11992
110 ^ 3889 mod 12317 =8939

Decrypting
3604 ^ 1297 mod 12317 =116
6862 ^ 1297 mod 12317 =104
11992 ^ 1297 mod 12317 =111
5341 ^ 1297 mod 12317 =109
551 ^ 1297 mod 12317 =115
11992 ^ 1297 mod 12317 =111
8939 ^ 1297 mod 12317 =110
```

class gen keys

/*
 * Algoritimo RSA
 * 26/11/2016 13:01
 * O quinto poder
 */

```
class keys {

    private $p;
    private $q;
    private $n;
    private $oN;
    private $e;
    private $d;
    private $keyPri;
    private $keyPub;

    function __construct() {
        $this->randoPnQ();
        $this->genN();
        $this->genE();
        $this->genD();
        $this->applyKeys();
    }

    private function ifPrime($val) {
        $event = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $val; $i ++) {
            (($val % $i) == 0) ? $event ++ : $event;
        }
        ($event == 2) ? $answer = true : $answer = false;
        return $answer;
    }

    private function randoPnQ() {
        echo '<br><strong>Gerando P</strong><br>';
        $loop = true;
        for ($i = 0; $loop != false; $i++) {
            $this->p = rand(rand(100, 109), rand(110, 119));
            ($this->ifPrime($this->p)) ? $loop = false : $loop;
        }
        echo '<br><strong>Gerando Q</strong><br>';
        $loop = true;
        $this->q = $this->p;
        for ($i = 0; $loop != false; $i ++) {
            $this->q ++;
            ($this->ifPrime($this->q)) ? $loop = false : $loop;
        }
        //$this->p = 17;
        //$this->q = 23;
        echo "gen p: $this->p and gen q: $this->q<br>";
    }

    private function genN() {
        echo '<br><strong>Gerando N</strong><br>';
        $this->n = $this->p * $this->q;
        echo '<br><strong>Gerando oN</strong><br>';
        $this->oN = ($this->p - 1) * ($this->q - 1);
        echo "gen N: $this->n and gen oN: $this->oN<br>";
    }

    private function fato($val) {
        $d = [1];
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $val; $i ++) {
            (($val % $i) == 0 ) ? array_push($d, $i) : $d;
        }
        return $d;
    }

    private function genE() {
        echo '<br><strong>Gerando E</strong><br>';
        $doN = $this->fato($this->oN);
        $voN = count($doN);

        $loop = true;
        for ($i = 0; $loop != false; $i ++) {
            $e = rand(1, $this->oN);
            $de = $this->fato($e);

            $diff = array_diff_assoc($doN, $de);

            if (count($diff) == ($voN - 1)) {
                $this->e = $e;
                $loop = false;
            }
        }
        //$this->e = 3;
        echo "gen E: $this->e<br>";
    }

    private function genD() {
        $loop = true;
        for ($i = 1; $loop != false; $i ++) {
            $d = ($i * $this->e) % $this->oN;
            if ($i >= 1 * 10 ** 100) {
                $loop = false;
                echo '<h2>Limite excedido!</h2>';
            } elseif ($d == 1) {
                if (strlen($i) > strlen($this->e)) {
                    $this->randoPnQ();
                    $this->genN();
                    $this->genE();
                    $i = 1;
                } else {
                    $loop = false;
                    $this->d = $i;
                }
            }
        }

        echo '<br><strong>Gerando D</strong><br>';
        echo "gen D: $this->d<br>";
    }

    private function applyKeys() {
        echo '<br><strong>Gerando keys</strong><br>';
        $this->keyPri = [$this->e, $this->n];
        $this->keyPub = [$this->d, $this->n];
        echo 'apply Keys';
    }

    public function getkeys() {
        return [$this->keyPri, $this->keyPub];
    }

}
```

class pre-coded

```
<?php

class codnDec {

    function __costruct() {

    }

    private function rstr($str, $op) {
        switch ($op) {
            case 'c':
                return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
                break;
            case 'd':
                return html_entity_decode($str);
                break;
            default:
                return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
                break;
        }
    }

    private function rgroup($cod) {
        $loop = true;
        while ($loop != false) {
            if (strlen($cod) == 3) {
                $loop = false;
            } else {
                $cod .= '0';
            }
        }
        return $cod;
    }

    public function cod($str) {
        $str = $this->rstr($str, 'c');

        $aStr = str_split($str);
        $vArray = count($aStr);
        $cAscii = null;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $vArray; $i ++) {
            $cAscii .= ord($aStr[$i]);
        }
        $aAscii = str_split($cAscii, 3);
        $r = end($aAscii);
        $key = array_search($r, $aAscii);
        $aAscii[$key] = $this->rgroup($r);
        return $aAscii;
    }

    public function dec($cod) {
        $r = null;
        $vCod = strlen($cod);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $vCod; $i += 2) {
            $temp = intval(substr($cod, $i, 2));
            if ($temp < 32) {
                $temp = intval(substr($cod, $i, 3));
                if ($temp > 128) {
                    echo "Assumption error";
                    die;
                }
                $i++;
            }
            $r .= chr($temp);
        }
        return $this->rstr($r, 'd');
    }
}
```

Call script. In this script the calculation is done to code and then to decode. Facilitating the analysis process.

```
<?php

/*
 * Include scripts aux.
 */
include_once 'gen-keys.php';
include_once 'codndec.php';

class rsa {
    /* Array d and n */

    public $privkey;

    /* Array e and n */
    public $publkey;

    function __construct() {
        /* Getting keys, pivate and public */
        $keys = new keys();
        $akeys = $keys->getkeys();
        $this->privkey = $akeys[0];
        $this->publkey = $akeys[1];
    }

    public function encrypt($msg) {
        $codndec = new codndec();
        echo '<br><strong>Pré codificando</strong><br>';
        $msgCod = $codndec->cod($msg);
        print_r($msgCod);
        echo '<br><strong>Obtendo chaves</strong><br>';
        $e = $this->privkey[0];
        $d = $this->publkey[0];
        $n = $this->privkey[1];
        echo '<br><strong>codificando 1/2</strong><br>';
        $x = count($msgCod);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i ++) {
            echo "<br> $msgCod[$i] ^ $e mod $n =" . $msgCod[$i] = bcpowmod($msgCod[$i], $e, $n);
        }
        echo '<br>';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i ++) {
            echo "<br> $msgCod[$i] ^ $d mod $n =" . $msgCod[$i] = bcpowmod($msgCod[$i], $d, $n);
        }
        echo '<br>' . $c = implode('', $msgCod);
        echo '<br><strong>codificando 2/2</strong><br>';
        return $cod = $codndec->dec($c);
    }

}

$str = 'thomson';
echo '<strong>Mensagem: </strong>' . $str;
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
$rsa = new rsa();
echo '<strong>Mensagem criptografada: </strong>' . $rsa->encrypt($str);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<strong>Private key is: </strong>' . implode('*', $rsa->privkey);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<strong>Public key is: </strong>' . implode('*', $rsa->publkey);


/*
$rsa = new rsa();
$keys = $rsa->getkeys();

echo 'Private key: ' . $keys[0][0] . '%' . $keys[0][1];
echo 'Public key: ' . $keys[1][0] . '%' . $keys[1][1];
*/
```

Comment: We can't find bugs in your code if you won't post the code. All I can tell you is the your decrypt exponent 695359 is incorrect. As its stands, without code, your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can place here?

Comment: I edited the post.